# JSF/Mojarra ExternalContext.redirect() creates a HttpSession

Tags: redirect, jsf, httpsession, mojarra

I'm playing with "stateless"/"transient" views in JSF and I noticed that invoking `ExternalContext.redirect()` causes a new session to be created.

So, I dug into the Mojarra (2.2.15) code:

```
// -> com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl:653

public void redirect(String requestURI) throws IOException {

    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    doLastPhaseActions(ctx, true);

    if (ctx.getPartialViewContext().isPartialRequest()) {
        if (getSession(true) instanceof HttpSession &&
            ctx.getResponseComplete()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        PartialResponseWriter pwriter;
        ResponseWriter writer = ctx.getResponseWriter();
        if (writer instanceof PartialResponseWriter) {
            pwriter = (PartialResponseWriter) writer;
        } else {
            pwriter = ctx.getPartialViewContext().getPartialResponseWriter();
        }
        setResponseContentType("text/xml");
        setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        addResponseHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
//        pwriter.writePreamble("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n");
        pwriter.startDocument();
        pwriter.redirect(requestURI);
        pwriter.endDocument();
    } else {
        ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(requestURI);
    }
    ctx.responseComplete();

}
```

Note that this method is the same also on [JSF-2.3 GitHub master](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/context/ExternalContextImpl.java#L731), nevertheless the check is not present at all on [MyFaces](https://github.com/apache/myfaces/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/context/servlet/ServletExternalContextImpl.java#L581)

I wonder why they included `getSession(true) instanceof HttpSession`, it seems pointless to me.

Can anyone explain the reason why shuch a check is there?

Comment: I'd say it is an omission in removing pieces of code when the 'transient' feature was implemented. But I'm no expert

Comment: Maybe you can find or get closer to the answer via [this commit](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/commit/3fefa2c9e24ac0bdc480b3d2949cbb929a5302a9) for [issue 2648](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/2652). I can't actually say why a session instance is needed to check if this is a Servlet context. There might be other less expansive ways to assert this.

Comment: Yes MyFaces did it better by checking whether the response is an instance of `HttpServletResponse`, but even they didn't throw the intended exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed not the correct behavior. It should simply have checked if the `response` is an instance of `HttpServletResponse`. It should also have done that before invoking its `sendRedirect()` method which in its current form could have thrown a `ClassCastException` in a Portlet environment with a poorly implemented bridge.

Technical reason for the explicit `instanceof` checks on `javax.servlet.http.*` classes  is because JSF is also available for a Portlet environment. There they use [`javax.portlet.*`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification) API instead of `javax.servlet.http.*` API. A well known example which you probably ever heard about is "[Liferay](https://www.liferay.com/)".

Comment: So that was just to check if the environment is Servlet or Portlet. I created the issue [Mojarra #4405](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4405). Thank you :)

Comment: @MicheleMariotti while I pointed you to the old mojarra github repo in order to find the commit, I don't know if this is still monitored. You should post the isse on the new repo at https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra

Comment: @Selaron thanks, I added the same issue to [eclipse-ee4j/mojarra #4649](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4649)